# Bookmark multiple line regex result in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a Logfile where I need to extract several lines in a new File. I can mark these Lines with the following Regex `Query .* message.*\r\n.*ApplicationGatewayID = 5009.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n` 
When I activate the Bookmark Line it only bookmarks the first line.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: you need to actually bookmark all matching lines (set the blue bullets), right? Not just *mark* (color the match red)?

Comment: i need to bookmark all the red lines and i have 420 Matches in 18'000 lines of Logs so I can't do it manually

Comment: I think you can solve the problem without all that. Use *Replace* dialog with `(.*Query .* message.*\R.*ApplicationGatewayID = 5009.*\R.*\R.*\R)|^(?!.*Query .* message).*\R?` as *regex* and `$1` as the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract multiline blocks of text with your regex, you may use *Replace* dialog with:

**Find What**: `(.*Query .* message.*\R.*ApplicationGatewayID = 5009.*\R.*\R.*\R)|^(?!.*Query .* message).*\R?`
**Replace With**: `$1`

The regex is of the form: `(<YOUR_REGEX_MATCHING_LINES>)|^(?!.*<STARTING_PART_OF_REGEX>).*\R?`.

**Details**

- `(.*Query .* message.*\R.*ApplicationGatewayID = 5009.*\R.*\R.*\R)` - a line with `Query` and then `message` words on it, then the next line that has `ApplicationGatewayID = 5009` on it and then 2 more lines, captured into Group 1 (`$1` refers to this value)
- `|` - or
- `^(?!.*Query .* message).*\R?` - start of a line (`^`) that has no `Query` and then `message` on it, then the whole line and optional linebreak after it are matched and eventually removed.

See the Notepad++ test:

[image]